# How do I remove a row that starts with "1", in many text files with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, label, file-writing, file-read

I have at least 3700 text files (labels actually) in directory along with same number of jpg/jpeg images.
among all those text files a few hundreds of them have text as:

```
1 0.19140625 0.50078125 0.3078125 0.9484375
```

I want to remove such line starting from 1 in every text file it is present in.
I tried following:

```
import os
import glob
import errno
path = '~/Documents/txt/*.txt'
path1 = '~/Documents/txt/'
files = glob.glob(path)
txtfile = []
temp_path = os.path.join(path1, 'temp.txt')
for name in files:
    try:
        with open(name, 'r') as f, open(temp_path) as temp:
            for line in f:
                if line.strip() == "1":
                    continue
                temp.write(line)

    except IOError as exc:
        if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR:
            raise
#print(txtfile)
```

Comment: So what's your problem exactly? BTW, you use temp to write and so you should `open(temp_path, 'w')`

Comment: `strip()` removes whitespace from the beginning and end of the line, it won't equate to the line beginning with "1" if there are other characters. `if line[0] == "1"` will.

Comment: Umm. Yes I see that open(temp_path, 'w'). I am learning object detection and creating my own custom object detection using YOLOv3. and I created labels but instead of one class I created labels for 2 in a few hundred images and that is why the model won't work.. Therefore I am trying to remove lines in text files which start from 1 i.e, class two

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob
import os

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
for name in glob.glob(path+'/*.txt'):
    raw_data = open(name, 'r')
    data_list = raw_data.read().splitlines()
    with open(name, "w") as new_file:
        for row in data_list:
            if row.startswith("1") is False:
                new_file.write(row + '\n')
```

Comment: There's a beautiful default str method called startswith, do you think that could prove even cleaner here? i.e. using `if not row.startswith("1"):`

Comment: @Arnaud yep instead of `if int(row[0]) != 1:` you can put `if row.startswith("1") == False:`

Comment: I think that it is more adapted here as it directly compares strings and is more readable: why would you cast to int first?

Comment: Yes I have tried using line.startswith("1"). and I don't understand what mistake I am making here.

Comment: I don't want to create new files

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following:

```
path = '/home/mzaid/Documents/txt/*.txt'
for name in glob.glob(path):
    try:
        with open(name, 'r+') as fl:
            for line in fl:
                if line.startswith("1"):
                    #not sure what to do here
    except IOError as exc:
        if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR:
            raise
```